# My program of infix to postfix gives runtime error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, runtime-error, infix-notation

Below is an simple program to convert infix expression to postfix expression. It takes an infix expression in main program and after passing values in function converter, it returns a postfix expression as string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int priority(char o) {
    if (o == '(' || o == ')')
        return -1;
    else if (o == '*' || o == '/')
        return 2;
    else if (o == '+' || o == '-')
        return 1;
    else if (o == '^' )
        return 3;
}
string converter(stack <char>s, string in) {
    string pf;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        if ((in[i] >= 'a' && in[i] <= 'z') || (in[i] >= 'A' && in[i] <= 'Z') ){
            pf+= in[i];
        }
        else if (in[i] == '(') {
            s.push(in[i]);
        }
        else if (in[i] == ')') {
            while (s.top() != '(' && (!s.empty())) {
            char temp = s.top();
            pf += temp;
            s.pop();
            }
        }
        else  {
            if (s.empty()) {
                s.push(in[i]);
            }
            else {
                if (priority(in[i]) > s.top()) {
                    s.push(in[i]);
                }
                else if (priority(in[i]) == s.top()&&(in[i]=='^')) {
                    s.push(in[i]);
                }
                else {
                    while (priority(in[i]) <= s.top()&&(!s.empty())) {

                        char temp = s.top();
                        pf += temp;
                        s.pop();
                    }
                    s.push(in[i]);
                }
            }


        }
        
        }
    while (!s.empty()) {
        char temp = s.top();
        pf += temp;
        s.pop();
    }
        return pf;
    

}
int main() {
    string infix,postfix;
    cout << "input an infix expression"<<endl;
    cin >> infix;
    stack <char> s;
    postfix = converter(s, infix);
    cout << "Postfix expression is:" << postfix;
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I try to run the program, it gives runtime error.
It works till taking an infix expression but the function aborts abnormally.
I can't find the bug. I use visual studios. Is it a problem in my visual studios or a logic error, really don't know.

Comment: You should try debugging your code, that would be helpful. If you need our help, then you will need to provide more information, like what your error is.

Comment: It's not a problem with your Visual Studio. Your code contains multiple logical errors (bugs). You need to debug the code carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
while (priority(in[i]) <= s.top()&&(!s.empty()))
```

Accessing a stack's top when it's empty invokes undefined behavior, and that's exactly what's happening here, as `priority(in[i]) <= s.top()` will be checked first.

You should move the `!s.empty()` condition first. If it evaluates to true then the second condition will not be checked. This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```
while (!s.empty() && priority(in[i]) <= s.top())
```

Comment: That worked! THANK YOU.. but why does the order matter... it has to check both conditions any how..

Comment: It doesn't. Read the link I attached :-)